# Logstash file limit?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash

I am running `logstash 1.4.1` and `ES 1.1.1`. Logstash is reading log files from a central server (multiple servers logs present here usomg rsyslog), so for each day a dir like `2014-11-17` is created and file is created.

Problem I faced was that the first time I ran logstash it gave

Caused by: `java.net.SocketException: Too many open files`

So then I changed the nofile limit to **64000** in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and it worked fine.

Now, my problem is that with new files being created each day my number of files number will go on increasing and logstash will keep a handle on all open files.

How do others handle log streams when number of files are too large to be handled?

Shall I set it to unlimited?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you archive the files from your server, logstash will stop watching them and release the file handle.

If you don't delete or move them, maybe there's a file pattern that only matches new files?  Sometimes the current file is "foo.log" before being rotated to "foo.2014-11-17.log".

Logstash Forwarder (a lighter-weight shipper than the full Logstash) has a concept of "Dead Time", where it will stop watching a file if it's been inactive (default 24 hours).